# Input is being excluded when form is submitted

Tags: php

1 Things first: My I have abbreviated `htmlspecialchars()` to `h()` in my custom API.

Have an input where everything else is showing up when I run `<pre><?php print_r($_POST) ?></pre>` But this particular input isn't

```
<input id="phone_description_<?php echo $phone_count; ?>" type="text"
         name="phone[<?php echo $phone_count; ?>]['phone_description']"
         value="<?php echo h($phone['phone_description']); ?>"
    <?php
    if ($phone['phone_description'] == 'Primary') {
        echo ' disabled';
    }
    ?>
         placeholder="e.g. Adwords Tracking Number"
         class="phone_desc"
/>
```

$phone_count is a counting variable in a foreach loop just FYI. Not really sure why an input with a name attribute isn't even showing up in the $_POST array.

**Edit**

Here is the code that is generated from the above code

```
<input id="phone_description_0" type="text" name="phone[0]['phone_description']" value="Primary" disabled placeholder="e.g. Adwords Tracking Number" class="phone_desc" />
```

Comment: show the generated html from this script.

Comment: Look at the DOM in the browser's console, also use View Source to see the full HTML.

Comment: I have a few years of experience in PHP and form handling, but I haven't come across such a [ square bracket syntax except in arrays. May be I am wrong. Is it okay to use square brackets for concatenating two php variables together? other commentators, please please advise.

Comment: Sorry everybody, I went home and didn't have access to the code, posting the code here in about 2 minutes

Comment: If it is disabled it won't be submitted I guess

Comment: @Padmanabhan Yes it is correct. but it isn't to concatenate. it is to story it in an associative array within POST. This helps with dynamically created content where there is more than one of a type of input. I.E. more than one phone description since there are multiple phones.

Comment: Ok, But, I had tried your code with dummy values. The square bracketed stuff didn't resolve or submit.. If you can show your code with some example values and the expected result, I might help you. (I am doing tons of PHP parsing and complicated Ajax stuff..)

Comment: I've figured it out. I had disabled this input. I should have been using readonly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input will be skipped by POST when it is disabled. Use "readonly" instead.